# Comprehensive description of OneNote sync available?

Tags: pdf, sync, microsoft-onenote-2013

Created a new notebook, 16 sections and about 1,500 pages of imported PDF (print to OneNote). Since then it has synced at least 15 GB up to OneDrive. Yet, on my other devices only three or four sections are available, and not even all pages in that section.

I cannot figure out what is going on here, nor do I know where to check the size of this particular notebook as it exists in some kind of coded folder. Hence I'm wondering if there is any comprehensive tutorial or explanation on how sync works in detail and if there are any tools that enable a user to take better control of the sync process. Google provides some material but so far it has been less than comprehensive.

*Update*
After looking in 
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\15.0\Backup\Edo
I find that the the sixteen sections has a total of app. 815 MB.
I realize that there is a lot going on in communication protocols and such, but more than 20 times that and still no progress on 12 of the sections? Seems to me that something isn't working as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I cannot answer your question about the detailed explanation of how OneNote sync works, I can say that it is still built around the old `groove.exe` client from when Microsoft purchased the technology.

However, the symptoms you mention are indicative of a corrupt copy of the notebook in the cache. I've only seen this once before but Microsoft do have a technote on the issue somewhere (sorry I haven't been able to find it).

The "fix" is to delete the local copy of the notebook.

I think in your case, you probably need to create a new notebook on the server and then copy over the notes.

Notebooks are simply a collection of compressed XML files and some folders and they are very easy to copy around.

Comment: I found, thanks to another forum, that there is a <b>onenote.exe /safeboot</b> command that lets you delete the cache. After that I restore the non-synced notebooks buy opening each section from the local backup and do a separate sync. I believe it was simply a matter of sync overload.